# Time travel short(?) story about love and an outdated calendar

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, love

So, I only vaguely remember this story. To make it harder, I don't remember if I read it in English or in German. Probably English, though I am not sure, as I read it a long time ago.

PLOT: 
A guy wants to meet with a girl in the past I think, but he is disorganized/messy and has an outdated calendar or something. To achieve this, he has some woman (I think) with him, who would grant him the time travel wish. I remember her as pretty bossy, and curt, short patience and easily annoyed.

He is supposed to meet this (different) girl at some place at a specific day and date, but she never shows up when he goes. The woman who is helping him then asks, "Wait, which year is this calendar here in your room?" and he says something like "oh, it's from last year, I never got a current one", and she gets pissed off cause he used the previous' year's weekdays to mark a date or something.

He asked the woman (fairy/genie?) to send him, for example, to a Tuesday, October 2nd, but on the current year, October 2nd is a Wednesday, so he's stuck in a day that doesn't exist or something, and it might have been a one-way trip?

And the end of the story is something along the lines of the genie-woman saying, "search for her in the day of tomorrow" (or something along those lines), but he is stuck forever searching for her in the day of tomorrow, because he's 1 day behind with the same date.

That's all I remember really.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).